# swift - UserDefaults wrapper

Tags: swift

I want to make **userDefaults easier to use**. I write this code.
But I don't want to create a allKeys enum(cases voipToken, userId, userName, displayName,...) as the key path for my property. 
If I want add a var accessToken to struct LoginInfo, I must add a case accessToken to enum AllKeys. I use CoreStore.key(.accessToken) get a keyPath for CoreStore.LoginInfo.accessToken.

```
import Foundation

struct CoreStore {

    //    static let sharedInstance = CoreStore()

    //    private init(){}

    private static let keyPrefix = "_shared_store_"

    enum allKeys: String {
        case accessToken
    }

    static func key(_ key: allKeys) -> String {
        return keyPrefix + key.rawValue
    }

    struct LoginInfo: CoreStoreSettable,CoreStoreGettable { }
}

extension CoreStore.LoginInfo {

    static var accessToken: String? {
        set {
            set(value: newValue, forKey: CoreStore.key(.accessToken))
        }
        get {
            return getString(forKey: CoreStore.key(.accessToken))
        }
    }
//    ...
}

protocol CoreStoreSettable {}
extension CoreStoreSettable {

    static func set(value: String?, forKey key: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
    }
}

protocol CoreStoreGettable {}
extension CoreStoreGettable {

    static func getString(forKey key: String) -> String? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

**Questions**:

1. Is there a way to **remove** "enum allKeys"?
2. Should I use **sharedInstance**? **Why**?

**I tried** :

```
static var accessToken: String? {
    set {
        let keyPath = \CoreStore.Loginfo.accessToken 
        let keyPathString = keyPath.string
        set(value: newValue, forKey: keyPathString)
    }
    get {
        return getString(forKey: CoreStore.key(.accessToken))
    }
}
```

I get error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: The above code is what I am using now, and it is very convenient to use now. I am asking this question, just thinking about whether it can be optimized. For example, is enum allkeys redundant?

Comment: Please only include relevant code

Comment: @Carpsen90 I removed the redundant code

Comment: I think storing `accessToken ` using UserDefaults is a bad practice, UserDefaults  store everything on a plist file (not encrypted), meaning that someone who have access to this plist file and with a sniffer can compromise your backend. For this kind of values I always use the keychain